# How to restrict openfiledialog to select only directory and folders not a file in c#

Tags: c#

I have an input files with .si extensions.On button click i m trying to display all files with .si extension which are exist in diretory or in a particular folder.

Comment: Is [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) an option?

Comment: No, i cant see any option like FolderBrowserDialog

Comment: FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog(); dialog.ShowDialog();

Comment: Okay sorry. There is no option of class [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) that's called FolderBrowserDialog. I mean you should use [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of OpenFileDialog.

Comment: But I don't think FolderBrowserDialog alone will help you to achieve your target.

Comment: @PalaniKumar Yes you're maybe right. The title told me - I didn't read the text I only read the title. Maybe you should set the [DefaultExt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.defaultext(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `"si"` and set the [Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) to `"SI-Files (*.si)|*.si"`. Both properties are contained in [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks .I got the answer.Right now i m using FolderBrowserDialog .